# FPDF generated attachment for e-mail consists out of weird characters

Tags: php, email, fpdf, email-attachments

I have been using FPDF for the last two years to generate a PDF file. After this file has been generated it is e-mailed to me. I recently installed the exact same script on a new server. For one or other reason the generation of the PDF works since I don't get a error message. The message that I receive on the email is straight text and looks like:

--4aca5942d8bd7e7d523d8b2d71c6b1ea--
or
--d7582bf6769dd1fa2ee8f05cb04cf445--

every message is different.

The stripped code is:

```
require('class.phpmailer.php');
require('fpdf.php');
define('FPDF_FONTPATH','font/');

//Create new PDF
$pdf=new PDF();
$pdf->AliasNbPages(); 
$pdf->company = $business;

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false);
$pdf->AddPage('P');

// email stuff
$tijd = time();
$datum = date('j-m-Y', $tijd);
$bestandsnaam = $usernameinlog."-".$datum;
$from = "magazijnbeheer@".$website;
$subject = "Voorraad mutatie door ".$usernameinlog; 
$message = "<p>Zie bijlage voor een mutatieoverzicht.</p>";

// a random hash will be necessary to send mixed content
$separator = md5(time());

// carriage return type (we use a PHP end of line constant)
$eol = PHP_EOL;

// attachment name
$filename = $bestandsnaam.".pdf";

// encode data (puts attachment in proper format)
$pdfdoc = $pdf->Output("", "S");
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfdoc));

// main header (multipart mandatory)
$headers  = "From: ".$from.$eol;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol; 
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"".$eol.$eol; 
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol;
$headers .= "This is a MIME encoded message.".$eol.$eol;


// The actual message
$headers .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;
$headers .= $message.$eol.$eol;

// Bijlage
$headers .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"".$eol; 
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment".$eol.$eol;
$headers .= $attachment.$eol.$eol;
$headers .= "--".$separator."--";


mail($emailemployee, $subject, "", $headers);
```

Does anyone know what is going wrong, am I missing a parameter in the php.ini?
once again: this same code worked on a different server, so I think some setting is wrong or I forgot to install something.

:-) Thanks,

Alex

Comment: It looks like some hash value - can you post some code? Like pdf generation or e-mail sending snippets.

Comment: I added the code above for clarification!

Answer (score 0):

`$eol = PHP_EOL;` is likely to cause problems if your server isn't running Windows.

Each line in an email MUST end in CRLF, irrespective of OS, so you should hard-code `$eol = "\r\n";`

Sometimes, servers and clients will cope with either CR or LF, but it's non-standard and they really don't have to.

.

---

If you still have problems after this, please can you add the message source to the question (for brevity, perhaps trim the base64 bit to 2 lines)?

Comment: The message source is a really long piece of code, but it works on a linux server. and what do you mean with trim the base64 bit to 2 lines? Alex

Comment: @AlexvanRijs The main reason that the source is long is that it contains the attachment (the attachment will appear in the email as a long base64-encoded string) it will be lots of lines that look like `AAAQAgAIAAAALQEAAAEQAwABAAAAAwAAAAIQAwABAAAAAAAAABAQAwABAAAAAQAAABEQCgABAAAA`.  To help you, I really need to see this source (but I don't need to see all of the attachment, so you can remove all but any two of the base64 lines from the source). You can either post the source on this question, or post it somewhere else and link to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
mail($emailemployee, $subject, "", $headers);
```

your basically sending a empty message with the whole content somehow stuffed into 
$headers....

Try putting everything below `$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol;` in a $body variable instead of $headers and then send with

```
mail($emailemployee, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

(also replace `$eol = PHP_EOL` with `$eol = "\r\n"` as suggested by SimonMayer)

Comment: Gryphius, I as suggested before I updated the code by altering the $eol variable to "r\n". If I change the $header to $body and add this variable to the mail function it doesn't send an e-mail at all. On the other side if I leave this to $header and leave $eol = "\r\n"; I do get a message, but still in a hash (--41e12eb8038d06a471d8a74519f62fe5--)